# Does the size of document affect mongo's performance?

Tags: performance, mongodb

If a document size is 1KB and Mongo can insert or remove 8000 documents per second does that mean that given document size 8KB, Mongo will be able to process only 1000 documents?

Comment: I'm never heared about this constraint... You could read this http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/ manual about MongoDB limits.

Comment: Where did you get this data? There's a limitation for single document size - 16MB (afaik) but that's all

Comment: it's probably not linear. if you are curious, measure it. it all depends on where the bottleneck is.

Comment: There is a performance hit when using large documents but your question makes no sense, why would it only be able to remove 1000 documents?

Answer (score 1):

Any disk write will depend on the hardware properties, OS and underlying file system. Most file systems read and write data in blocks which are usually multiple of physical block size. For example 4096 bytes block sizes are quite common.

All that means that if your doc is larger than 4K and you have a 4K block size then it will need 2 blocks to write your doc, on the other hand padding might come into consideration as well for docs much smaller than block size. I don't know how Mongo optimizes writes and maybe it does some bulk writes, chaining, etc.

In general you should not concern yourself with these questions, but if you really have tons of data and somehow you think document size causes performance degradation you can do some tests with various document sizes, ask Mongo support, and read Mongo source code.

Comment: MongoDB is not straight to disk as such the performance won't be instantly noticeable, if you mitigate the IO load behind the scenes there won't be any visible performance impact on writes there

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have did some test, the result is inserting docs in different size consume different time. Maybe the reason is disk io capacity or mongo capacity?

Comment: It should be proportional to the document size more or less. If docA size is 2 times less then docB size, then inserting lots of docA documents should be almost 2 times faster. It's not that straightforward because Mongo writes to journal and defers the rest of the IO for about a minute, but in a long run you would probably see that relationship. In reality maybe it would be only 1.5 times faster. Hard to say, but you can build that sort of graph.